# How do I run google's new "places_compat_compatify.sh" compatibility script?

Tags: android-studio, google-places-api

I am trying to migrate to the new places SDK provided by google and they provided a compatibility script winch automates the process: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#compat-script

But I think that, I am not running it the way I should, I am doing it from my terminal in Android Studio and when it runs it simply says "sed can't read file [file name] no such directory exist" I am writing the command with my project's directory.

Comment: I am also trying to find way to upgrade the sdk. Have you done with this?

Comment: yup, i added my answer just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it if anyone is interested that's how:

First, you need to download git bash in order to be able to run Linux commands on Windows, download it here: https://git-scm.com/downloads

Second copy the contents of: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#compat-script and save them somewhere on your local computer as: places_compat_compatify.sh

now open git bash and go to the directory where you saved the script (let's say you saved it on your desktop) then you must type cd Desktop, and cd D:\ if you saved it on then local disk D and so on, and then type dir to check if the file is there.

and then run this command ./places_compat_compatify.sh path-to-android-project 1.0.0

then open android studio and your implementations and import statements should be replaced with the new ones.

Comment: Will be the places_compat library migration also work after the timeline of July 29, 2019 for new places sdk or it is temporary solution?

Comment: it will still work, run the script and it will prepare everything for you including the import statements, but keep in mind that the place picker feature will no longer work after July 29 2019, so if you use that feature it's better to remove it or find an alternative, if you don't then run the script and you're all set.

Comment: I have used following APIs in my project,
           
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceLikelihood;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceLikelihoodBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocomplete;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceSelectionListener;

Will all these APIs work after running the script.

Comment: the script will replace those imports with new ones, just run the script and it will change them

Comment: I tried many ways but didn't work on Mac, it seems the script simply replacing with the new import and logo files. You can do it manually, it is even faster than struggle with the script. :P

Comment: sed: rename(): No such file or directory
sed: rename(): No such file or directory
sed: rename(): No such file or directory
sed: rename(): No such file or directory
sed: rename(): No such file or directory

Comment: It worked for me. I downloaded Git Bash and on console changed dir to folder of  places_compat_compatify.sh file and typed this: ./places_compat_compatify.sh C:/Path/to/androidproject 2.2.0 When reopened AS, it rewrote fragment in xml and imported classes into activity class too. I changed this too: SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment); I have in app gradle this: implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.2.0'

Answer (score 0):

The script didn't work for me either, it came up with errors such as:

```
sed: 1: "/Users/plo/dev/andro ...": invalid command code k
```

An alternative that worked for me was to use the Android Studios Find & Replace command (CMD+SHIFT+R), then replace the old import strings with the new ones. In addition, you should follow the other steps to:

1. replace the `play-services-places` dependency with the `places-compat` module
2. fix any emergent warnings or API methods on the Java/Kotlin code (minimal or none as the point of the compatibility library is to minimize code changes)
3. any other step prescribed by the [docs](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration) **(Install the Compatibility Library)** section

Answer (score -3):

If you use mac you will have an error "extra characters at the end of g command", for this you have to replace the line

```
find "$ {1}" -type f -regex "$ {2}" -not -regex ". * / \ (build \ | \ .idea \ | \ .git \ | \ .svn \) /.*" | xargs sed -i "" "s | $ {3} | $ {4} | g"
```

by

```
find "$ {1}" -type f -regex "$ {2}" -not -regex ". * / \ (build \ | \ .idea \ | \ .git \ | \ .svn \) /.*" | xargs sed -i "" "s | $ {3} | $ {4} | g"
```

with this the file works perfectly ./places_compat_compatify.sh

Comment: I have exactly the same error, but I don't see the difference between the 2 lines you gave...