# Why new places sdk clients compatibility script giving me - "Access is denied"

Tags: android, cmd, google-places-autocomplete

In the process of migration to the new Places SDK client, I got stuck with running the compatibility script, here is what I have done(using windows) :

**First** - I downloaded the content of the [compatibility script source code](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#compat-script) and saved it under the same name.

Here is the source come file path - `C:\Users\Tamir\Desktop\s`

**Second** - inside the cmd, I changed my path to the project path in this way :

```
C:\Users\Tamir>cd C:\Users\Tamir\Desktop\MyTruck
```

Now that I am on the proper path and want to run the script this is what I have done:

```
C:\Users\Tamir\Desktop\MyTruck> ./places_compat_compatify.sh <C:\Users\Tamir\Desktop\s> 1.0.0
```

After that, I got a message saying "Access is denied."

I followed the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#compatibility_script) all the way, what am I doing wrong here?

**Edit -** I also run the cmd as administrator but it did not helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the script, I had Android Studio's "Find & Replace" feature to do the text replacement for me. Then followed the rest of the documentation steps because the compatibility script is somewhat broken/not portable across platforms.

Related question and possibly relevant answers: [How do I run google's new "places_compat_compatify.sh" compatibility script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54490165/1145905)