# AutocompleteSupportFragment inside a fragment

Tags: android, google-places-api

SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment class is deprecated and also The Google Play Services Places SDK is deprecated.

So how to use new class AutocompleteSupportFragment inside a fragment?

Comment: In my app gradle I have this: implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.2.0'. In activity I can use this: import com.google.android.libraries.places.compat.ui.SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment; Or use this info too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54490165/how-do-i-run-googles-new-places-compat-compatify-sh-compatibility-script

Answer (score 2):

It is deprecated because there is a new SDK available and Google has a complete article on how to migrate to new SDK here:

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Edit: It looks like I didn't make it clear enough. According to above link, only:

> The Place Picker is deprecated.

Other than PlacePicker, there are no deprecations which means rest of the classes are still available to use.

You can add [AutoCompleteSearchFragment](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#autocomplete_widgets) like this:

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:name=
"com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
  />
```

This is also listed in the link I shared. As you can see, only the name has changed and some more functions were added.

As explained in the link, to initialize it, you have to do following steps:

- Initialize Places, passing the application context and your API key.
- Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment. Call setPlaceFields() to
  indicate the types of place data that you want to get.
- Add a PlaceSelectionListener to do something with the result, as well as
  handle any errors that might occur.

Code:

```
/**
 * Initialize Places. For simplicity, the API key is hard-coded. In a production
 * environment we recommend using a secure mechanism to manage API keys.
 */
if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
    Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "YOUR_API_KEY");
}

// Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));

autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
        Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
    }
});
```

Comment: this is not answer to my question. I haven't asked why deprecated.

Comment: @Zafer I've collected specific points relating to your question from the link I shared, that should clear it up.

Comment: adding AutocompleteSupportFragment into layout isn't problem. After that how to Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment inside  the fragment?

Comment: @Zafer Did you even open the link I shared? https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#autocomplete_widgets

It takes you to the exact spot on page which tells you how to do it dynamically. You are ignoring the source I've shared, please read the answer carefully.

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem when initiate AutocompleteSupportFragment inside a fragment.

```
AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
```

Instead of getSupportFragmentManager() need to use getChildFragmentManager()

```
AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
        getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
```

Comment: How is getChildFragmentManager() related to AutocompleteSupportFragment that you mentioned in your question? 
Your question should have been "Why I Can't find fragment inside another fragment using SupportFragmentManager?"
There is no mention of any problem or error in your question.

Comment: If I were mentioned getChildFragmentManager(), I would have found the answer already.